# How should I go about solving this lagrange equation containing vectors and matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-multiplier

I have a Lagrange equation which depends on a multiplier $\lambda$.
\begin{equation}
f(\lambda)=a^HR^{-1}a + \lambda(||a-\bar{a}||^2-\varepsilon)
\end{equation}
I know $\bar{a}$, $R$ and $\varepsilon$. $a$ and $\bar{a}$ are $M-$dimensional complex column vectors and $R$ is a real, symmetric $M\times M$ matrix. $x^H$ represents the conjugate transpose of $x$.

I have tried the conventional approach of calculating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda}=0$ and $\nabla_af=0$, which results in
\begin{equation}
a^HR^{-1} = \lambda(a-\bar{a})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
||a-\bar{a}||^2=(a-\bar{a})^H (a-\bar{a})=\varepsilon
\end{equation}
The equation for $\varepsilon$ is just my constraint which I'm already aware of. As far as I can tell this can't be solved - at least not using techniques that I'm aware of.

My aim is to eliminate $a$ so that I have an equation made up of known quantities and $\lambda$, which I can solve numerically for $\lambda$. Every approach I've tried has ended in a dead end, and I'm curious if there's a technique I'm unaware of that could help me out.

The Lagrange equation comes from Appendix A of [1].

[1] https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6381484

Comment: So you want to find $a$ such that $a^HR^{-1}a$ is minimized or maximized?

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. Minimized.

Comment: Got it, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the correct way to calculate the optimal points since I think your system of equation isn't correct. Still though, if you calculate the gradient wrt $\mathbf a$, then, the Hessian turns out to be all $0$s. This is because the function $\mathbf{a^HR^{-1}a}$ differentiated partially wrt strictly $\mathbf a$ is $\mathbf{a^HR^{-1}}$ which differentiated again is $\mathbf 0$. So your function is essentially a hyperplane in $M$ dimensions, which obviously has no absolute maxima or minima. Let's start:

Since $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb{C}^M$, each element $\mathbf a_i$ will be expressed as $x_i+iy_i$.

So your original lagrangian equation was

$$f(\lambda)=\mathbf{a^HR^{-1}a}+\lambda(||\mathbf{a-\bar{a}}||^2-\varepsilon)$$

The lagrangian multiplier method tells us to impose

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\mathbf a}f=\mathbf 0\ \ \text{and}\ \ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda}=0.$$

The latter is trivial so I'll simply do the gradient.

In index notation, the first function can be expressed as
$$\mathbf{a^HR^{-1}a}=R_{ij}^{-1}\bar{a_i}a_j,$$
for $i,j\in(1,...,M)$, being the matrix' rows and columns, respectively.

Now, taking the gradient of this, we get

$$(\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\mathbf a}(\mathbf{a^HR^{-1}a}))_k=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a_k}[R_{ij}^{-1}\bar{a_i}a_j]=R_{ij}^{-1}\bar{a_i}\dfrac{\partial a_j}{\partial a_k}=R_{ij}^{-1}\bar{a_i}\delta_k^j=R_{ik}^{-1}\bar{a_i},$$

for $k\in(1,...,M).$

What's left is taking the gradient of $\lambda(||\mathbf{a-\bar{a}}||^2-\varepsilon)$, which is what I think you did wrong (missed a $2$):

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\mathbf a}\lambda(||\mathbf{a-\bar{a}}||^2-\varepsilon))_k&=\lambda(\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\mathbf a}(||\mathbf{a-\bar{a}}||^2))_k\\
&=\lambda(\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\mathbf a}((\mathbf{a-\bar a})^H(\mathbf{a-\bar a})))_k\\
&=\lambda(\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\mathbf a}((\mathbf{\bar a-a})^T(\mathbf{a-\bar a})))_k\\
&=-\lambda(\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\mathbf a}(a_i-\bar a_i)(a_i-\bar a_i)))_k\\
&=-\lambda\dfrac{\partial(a_i-\bar a_i)^2}{\partial a_k}\\
&=-2\lambda(a_i-\bar a_i)\underbrace{\dfrac{\partial a_i}{\partial a_k}}_{\delta^i_k}=-2\lambda(a_k-\bar a_k).
\end{aligned}$$

So the system of equations we get is

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&R_{ik}^{-1}\bar a_i-2\lambda(a_k-\bar a_k)=0;\\
&||\mathbf{a-\bar a}||^2=\varepsilon.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Now it's time to use $\mathbf a_i=x_i+iy_i$:

For the first $M$ equations due to the gradient and the one due to the constraint, we can rewrite these elements explicitly as complex numbers:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{ik}^{-1}\bar a_i-2\lambda(a_k-\bar a_k)&=R_{ik}^{-1}\bar a_i-2\lambda(((x_k+iy_k)-(x_k-iy_k)))\\
&=R_{ik}^{-1}\bar a_i-i4\lambda y_k\\
&=R_{ik}^{-1}(x_i-iy_i)-i4\lambda y_k\\
&=R_{ik}^{-1}x_i-i(R_{ik}^{-1}y_i+4\lambda y_k).
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
||\mathbf{a-\bar a}||^2=(a_i-\bar a_i)^2=4y_i^2=\varepsilon.
$$

Having turned the gradient equations into a complex number that includes the unknowns, since it is equated to $0$, we will impose the real and imaginary parts to be $0$:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&R_{ik}^{-1}x_i-i(R_{ik}^{-1}y_i+4\lambda y_k)=0\iff
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&R_{ik}^{-1}x_i=0\\
&R_{ik}^{-1}y_i+4\lambda y_k=0
\end{aligned}
\right. \\
&4y_i^2=\varepsilon.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

For the real part, in view that the matrix' elements aren't necessarily all $0$, we obtain that all $x_i=0$, so $\mathbf a_i=iy_i$. As for the imaginary part equation, I'd combine the rest which only depend on $y_i$ and solve for them. Basically what we're left with is:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&R_{ik}^{-1}y_i+4\lambda y_k=0\\
&4y_i^2=\varepsilon.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

The general approach would be isolating $\lambda$ in one of the $k$ equations and substitute in another. At last, using the constraint equation, you'd find $y_i$ in terms of the rest of $y$s and then substitute again and again until you get all $y$s.

Comment: If the Hessian doesn't tell you anything about the points you found, I'd suggest using Weierstrass' extrem value theorem which consists in evaluating the function you want to minimize at the critical points at whichever gives the lowest value is the minimum